# How do I turn on a login page for Bugzilla?

Tags: security, mysql, authentication, bugzilla

I have Bugzilla 4.2.1 running on my Ubuntu 11.10, It working as it should and everything is fine.

Now when somebody accesses the URL www.myapplication.com/bugs without logging in, it allows the user to view bugs and all the product/version/etc.

How do I make sure that this doesn't happen, i.e. Anonymous user dont have any access except to the login page.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting in Administration -> Parameters -> User Authentication called "requirelogin" set this to "On"